# Angular bootstrap select field

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I am trying to create an angular bootstrap select field from inside a directive. The directive creates the following dom structure but the select field is empty.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="f for f in ["i","j","k"]"><option></option></select>
```

What is the correct way to create the select field in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use single quotes in side double quotes
2. `ng-model` is required.

Here is the code

```
<select ng-model="myChoice" class="form-control" ng-options="f for f in ['i','j','k']"></select>
```

Comment: i had to add the ng-model directive to get this working. The single quote wasnt the problem.